# Linux driver for FPGA hardware IP

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have an hardware  **IP** implemented on FPGA running linux with **RISCV** architecture, this IP contains all kinds of registers **:** registers to generate interrupts, registers to store data ..etc.
I would like to make a linux kernel  driver for this IP ,knowing that it will be called (ordered) by other devices (like CPU) to precisely generate interrupts and store data .
What type/class of driver should I choose  , which **kernel** API  could help me to code it .

Comment: Hi from a fellow old CPU fan. My two cents : A network interface class driver seems adequate.

Comment: IP for block IP( intellectual  property )  , there  is no relation with networking ! the CPU for exemple order my IP de generate IRQ by writing on his register .  please  why do you suggest network interface ?

Comment: Your intent si to make a linux kernel module able to dialog with the hardware IP, IP that should produce IRQ and store data. As it is, a network class driver seems fit to me. If not,  we need to know what kind of data would be stored/exchanged and in what way (single status byte ? output from an ADC ? input for a DAC ?) to see which driver class would fit.

Comment: Haha, Z80 speaks to @Zilog80. You need to add a nickname so person will see a notification.

Comment: @Zilog80, precise IRQs and storing data is not a network class driver. PTP what you may refer to, but it's only about clock source (not exactly IRQ generation), so there is insufficient information given, I'm going to vote for closing this Q.

Comment: "Driver" can mean different things, depending on whether you mean the interface at the bottom end (bus client driver) or the interface at the top end (char, block or network device driver). At the bottom end, you probably want a "platform" driver with device tree support.